# How to rename pandas dataframe with a name that includes special characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading an excel file and dumping the content into a pandas dataframe. I am using sqlalchemy to upload the entire dataframe into a MySQL database.

Functionally everything works, however I ran into an issue when I tried to upload an excel document where the columns included the % symbol.

One of my functions renames the dataframe's headers with row[0], deletes row[0], and then re-indexes.

When I try to read this dataframe it throws an error that there is an illegal hex character (%)- which is true.

I don't want to modify this column name because it is how it comes up in the excel file I'm uploading, and the database expects it to remain the same.

How can I get the pandas dataframe to accept the special (%) character in the column name? e.g. "Sales % of Total"

```
example data:
         [0]           [1]
    [0] Sales | Sales % of Total
    [1] $100  |        50%

dataframe.rename(columns=dataframe.iloc[0]).drop(dataframe.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)

expected output:
       [Sales]  [Sales % of Total]
    [0] $100  |        50%
```

Throws error:

URLDecover: Illegal hex  characters in escape (%) pattern - Error at index 0

Answer (score 1):

## Try this (replaceing 'df' for whatever your dataframe is called:

```
df.rename(columns={0:'Sales', 1:'Sales % of Total'}, inplace=True)
```

see the pic below for the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## You might also simply use

```
df.columns = ['Sales','Sales % of Total']
```

to define column names as you like.

You might also consider using this tip while reading the excel file so as to avoid the rename headers, delete, and re-indexing steps.

[Python pandas, How could I read excel file without column label and then insert column label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709108/python-pandas-how-could-i-read-excel-file-without-column-label-and-then-insert)